# Tomcat 8 JSP application not load external jar files copied in WEB-INF/LIB Folder

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jar

I am developing jsp webapp and running it through `ROOT/myprojectFolder` of the `Tomcat 8`. All pages are working fine. But in one .jsp page, i want to import and external .jar file, say `json-simple.1.1.1.jar`. [As per this link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)under the Bold Heading of **`WebappX:`**, *`.... resources in JAR files under the /WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application...`*. So I have put `json-simple.1.1.1.jar` in `ROOT/myprojectFolder/WEB-INF/lib` folder. But when I run the .jsp page on browser, I get the error of **`JsonArray cannot be resolved to a type`**.

I have tried everything possible since one week and even spoke to few .jsp programmers but couldn't resolve this error. Please advise on correcting this problem.

PS: I ain't using Eclipse and do not want to use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it..

The actions as I mentioned in my `Question` were correct. The Problem is in the way I tried importing the `jar library`. I changed the following statement

```
<%@ page import="json-simple.*" %>
```

to

```
<%@ page import="org.json.*" %>
```

and it works sweet. The problem was I was trying to import by file name. So the Lesson is do not use the `.jar`  `file name` but use the `directory structure` in the `.jar file` which can be seen if the `.jar file` is opened with `WinZip.exe`.

NOTE: One More thing I realised is that there are `two .jar file`s that need to be used that is the one I already mentioned and the second is `java-json.jar` Else it is not working.